# Will my mass increase in my perspective while approaching near the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, inertial-frames, observers

Suppose I start my journey by a spaceship accelerate the velocity to 0.7c from Earth. Now the question arises that-
Will my mass increase gradually as I'm going to a speed of .7c in my perspective and what will be the changes in others perspective?
And also what will be the changes of mass of that spaceship?

Comment: Hint:  If your mass increased "in your perspective", you'd know you were moving.

Comment: You are going 0.99999972 times the speed of light right *now* (relative that cosmic ray right *there*, of course). Has your mass changed?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes people talk about "relativistic mass" which depends on your reference frame... this is perhaps what you're thinking of when you talk of your mass increasing as you approach the speed of light. However, more typically if a physicist says "mass" they mean the "invariant mass" or "rest mass" which is just your energy content (divided by the speed of light squared) in the frame of reference in which you are at rest.  This isn't reference frame dependent.  So using that sense of mass, no one would say your mass increases as you accelerate.  Rather they would say that it takes more and more energy for you to achieve increasing speed, but not due to a change in your rest mass.

But even using the "relativistic mass" definition, it is still the case that your mass doesn't increase in your own reference frame.  In your inertial frame of reference, you are standing still, and the universe is moving around you.  So in that frame your relativistic mass is constant and equal to your rest mass.

Answer (score 0):

The mass of your spaceship and your mass is not affected in your frame of reference. However from an outter stationnary observer measuring your mass in some kind of way would see it increase, they would see your spaceship contract along its direction of motion and they would even see, if they could look at a clock in your spaceship, that your clock tics slower than theirs. On the other hand, you would see nothing change from your perspective, but you would observe the same changes if you look at the observers frame from the window.

So who's right? Both! And who's moving? There's no way to be sure!

Comment: "There's no way to be sure" should be "There's no way to make sense of the question."